# while running rake spec error Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, selenium, specifications

while running rake spec in rails i get the below error:

**Failure/Error: visit "/users/sign_up"
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
       unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)**

Can any one suggest for this error

Comment: what OS, FF version and selenium gem version do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your selenium-webdriver is up to date

Your GemFile should include the following:

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add selenium-webdriver to your Gemfile

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.25.0'
```